# Qt block ApplicationWindow in Background, if other is in Foreground

Tags: qt, background, block, applicationwindow

I'm working with QtQuick and created a settings-window (ApplicationWindow), which shows after click on the settings button. The problem is, that i can still click on the main-window. The settings-windows just goes behind the main-window and "disappeared", till i move the main-window.
Can I block the Main-Window while settings-menu opened? Furthermore is there a possibility remove the minimze and maximize buttons of the settings-windows in qml?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: dialogs and modality will be your friends here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term that describes what you need is called Modality. You can set the **window modality** property, as explained here:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#WindowModality-enum

Also, each Qt window has a **type** property, as explained here:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#WindowType-enum

Set the type that fits you most.

As both are regular QObject properties you can set them via QML.